# coefficient of $x$ in a determinant

Tags: determinant

What is the coefficient of $x$ in the expansion of the determinant$\begin{vmatrix}
(1+x)^2 & (1+x)^4 &    (1+x)^6  \\ 
(1+x)^3 & (1+x)^6 & (1+x)^9  \\ 
(1+x)^4 & (1+x)^8 & (1+x)^{12}  \\  
\end{vmatrix}$.

I simplified the determinant to be $x^3(1+x)^{16}(x+2)$,how will i find coefficient of $x$?Someone help me in getting answer?

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct answer? In case this is true, $x$ has a zero coefficient.

Comment: @BolzWeir,Sir you can verify yourself.

Comment: You multiply $x^3$ by another polynom. There is cannot be terms with $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^3(x+2)(x+1)^{16} = x^4(x+1)^{16}+2x^3(x+1)^{16}= a_1x^3+a_2x^4+\cdots + a_{20}x^{20}$. It appears that the term $bx$ does not exist, as suggested by @BolzWeir so we can take $b = 0$.